# Module not found

Tags: blackberry

I developed a game which is running on any device which have OS 6. When we run this game on lower OS 6 then a problem occur :
Module 'net_rim_ui_api' not found
Please tell me the solution of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally this error comes when the module is missing , i think you have used some API and it create two or more ".cod" file please check in you deliverables folder in your project and install all ".cod" files.

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

The SDKs are not forward compatible. Meaning, if you compile an app for OS 6, it won't run on OS 5. However, they are **backward** compatible, meaning an app compiled for OS 5 **will** run on OS 6. There isn't something you can include in your project to make it work the other direction, you just have to set the target JRE to a 5.0 (or lower) version.